# Is it possible to stop Tkinter window freezing during update?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a small python project that requires data to be pulled from a network and displayed every second (which is how often it changes) for a scientific application. 3 of these things are simply numbers, while another is a 128x128 camera image, which is brought in as an `ndarray` and drawn using matplotlib's `imshow` to a tkinter canvas.

I've tried two methods - using `aniamtion.FuncAnimation()` and `after(interval, function)`, and both have the same result, which is that while the frame updates, the window can't be moved. and it feels jerky.

I assume that's something that can't be overcome (and probably doesn't matter)? I thought that perhaps multi-threading might help so the main window is on one thread, while the updated data can be on another?

Thanks!

Below is the basic code which now includes threading, and the error when closing the window is fixed by adding an event to the window close function, and also a few `break` commands while getting data that checks if the window is closed *before* it tries to interact with a GUI item that doesn't exist.

```
import blah, blah, blah

global safe_shutdown, window_status, my_thread
safe_shutdown = False
window_status = True

window = tk.Tk()

def widow_close():
    window_status=False
    while True:
        if safe_shutdown == True:
            window.destroy
            return False

def get_updates():
    while True:
        #code to go get data from network

        if window_status == False:
            safe_shutdown == True:
            break

        #more code to place data on the GUI
        if window_status == False:
            safe_shutdown == True:
            break

        #only get updates once a second
        time.sleep(1)

    print "thread complete"

my_thread= threading.Thread(target=get_updates, args=()).start()

window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", window_close)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert, so I'm not sure if there's a better solution. But I've had success with two separate solutions:

1: While it is not recomended to have the tkinter loop in a thread, you are allowed to have the data updating the tkinter app in a thread. This has worked pretty good for me in the past simply using the threading package. The thread will then just set the various stuff in need of a refresh.

2: Call the update_idletasks() on the window to force it to update. This can then be added at various places in you code where it would make sense to update the view.

Solution 1 whould take care of all stuttering, while solution 2 might just make it a bit better. I suppose it depends on your implementation.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give option 1 a go first, then 2 and will report back

Comment: Sounds good. Remember to not invoke join() on thread, as that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your help. It took a bit to understand how to make use of the thread method.
That worked fine the first time i run it, but the second time I get errors `(TclError: bad window path name ".286127688L")` and `Unhandled exception in thread started by <function get_updates at 0x000000000A6F26D8>`

Comment: Actually, I think I know what's causing it, I just don't know how to fix it.

I think the issue stems from the fact that `get_updates` draws to the GUI and is its own thread, and so when I close the GUI `get_updates()`  can't find the GUI to update to. I would handle that by only running the thread if the GUI is also running, but how to make that true?

Comment: So the entire tkinter app is closed, or just the window you are trying to change?

Comment: The entire app.
for the sake of testing, i only have one window, which i called window (i.e. `window = tk.Tk()`). I could easily have called it root or something. Below is a basic version of the code:
 

`import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import thread

window = tk.Tk()
def get_updates():
    #gets data and draws it on a canvas
    #Sleeps for one second before getting it again

try:
    thread.start_new(get_updates,())

except Exception:
    import traceback
    print traceback.format_exc()

window.mainloop()`

Comment: wow... that didn't display as I intended and i can't edit it now.  I'll try again below.